# How to add brackets in createfilter method

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to add a set of filter conditions with brackets through the createfilter method, but in suitescript 2.0 I did not find an effective method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter expression.

Create the search in the UI, and then load the search using `search.load()`. You can inspect the filter expression that way.

```
const mySearch = search.load({id:'customsearch_mysearch'});
log.debug('expression', mySearch.filterExpression);
```

The filter expression is an array. You can set the filters when you create the search.

Something like;

```
search.create({
    type: 'customer',
    filters: myFilterArray,
                columns: [
                    search.createColumn({name: 'entityid'})
                ]
```